how to change ui of react-spreadsheet-import component
I want to remove the buttons from last step of react-spreadsheet-import component.
button names are :

Discard selected rows
Show only rows with errors


I tried customTheme prop to remove this button but didn't find any solution:

here is a simple code of how I used react-spreadsheet-import :
import { ReactSpreadsheetImport } from "react-spreadsheet-import";

const fields = [
  {
    label: "code",
    key: "code",
    fieldType: {
      type: "input",
    },
    alternateMatches: ["CODE"],
    validations: [
      {
        rule: "required",
        errorMessage: "code is required",
        level: "error",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Sales",
    key: "quantity",
    fieldType: {
      type: "input",
    },
    validations: [
      {
        rule: "required",
        errorMessage: "Sale is required",
        level: "error",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "name",
    key: "name",
    fieldType: {
      type: "input",
    },
    alternateMatches: ["NAME"],
  },
];
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function CsvImport() {

  const onConfirm = async (data) => {
    const body = {
      date,
      data: data?.validData ?? [],
    };  

    const result = await enterdata(body);

    dispatch(
      openSnackbar({
        result,
        success_message: result?.data?.message || "Data enter successfully!",
      })
    );

    onCloseDialog();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactSpreadsheetImport
        isOpen={true}
        fields={fields}
        onSubmit={onConfirm}
        translations={{
          uploadStep: {
            title: `Import sales for ${moment(date).format("Do MMM YYYY")}`,
          },
        }}
      />
      // what changes i should make here to remove the buttons from last step of
      // reactspreadsheetimport component
    </>
  );

}

Above code will render like this:


Currently, this library does not expose a direct option to hide such a button through the component properties. However, you can work around this in the following ways.
By inspecting the component, you might find a className or data-testid associated with the button. In this case, the button can be hidden with a simple CSS style:
[data-testid="show-errors-button"] {
  display: none;
}

If you prefer to do it programmatically, you can use a useEffect.
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { ReactSpreadsheetImport } from 'react-spreadsheet-import';

const MySpreadsheetImport = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector('[data-testid="show-errors-button"]');
    if (button) {
      button.remove();
    }
  }, []);

  return <ReactSpreadsheetImport />;
};

export default MySpreadsheetImport;

